# How to join Google App Engine's logging table in BigQuery with Error Reporting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-error-reporting

[Google App Engine (GAE) creates a table](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#bigquery-overview) for each day of logging with lines containing several logs information, such as "status" (e.g.: `500`, `404`), etc.

Yet, this table does not contain the Resolution Status for the errors in Error Reporting. E.g.:

[image]

At the moment, I would like to get how many "Acknowledged" errors happen per day. I can get which errors happen per day through the `appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_*` (e.g.: `appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20211130`). However, I don't know how can I get if the error is **Acknowledged** or **Open**.

Does anyone know how can I combine those information, or at least if Error Reporting saves its information in any BigQuery table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing Google documentation to help with your question, apparently, it is impossible to get the resolution status.

You can view your errors on the Error Reporting page of your GCP Console, which displays a list of all errors in the order of frequency. Errors with the same root cause are grouped together. The error reporting list provides the following information for all reported errors:

- Resolution status
- Occurrences
- Users
- Error
- Seen in
- First seen
- Last seen
- Response code

In case you would like to have more information, you can review the [viewing error](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors#error_reporting_list) documentation.

Now, as I said, there is no way to get the resolution status; however, what you can try to do is a feature request.

Here is some documentation that shows what you can get with the API, it could help you with the feature request.

- https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers
- https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent

Additionally, here is a link I found regarding the [Error Processing and Log Monitoring](https://doc.oroinc.com/cloud/maintenance/errors/) documentation using GCP.